# Obtain text within script tag using Jsoup

Tags: javascript, java, android, jsoup

How to get value http://api.tivi8k.net/viettel/?cid=154&token=-OWPRmOicPqIKsK97SmOlQ&e=1500542988 using Jsoup?

[image]

html:

```js
xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open("GET", "http://api.tivi8k.net/viettel/?cid=154&token=-OWPRmOicPqIKsK97SmOlQ&e=1500542988", false);
xmlhttp.send();
link = xmlhttp.responseText;

player = new Clappr.Player({
  source: link,
  parentId: '#player',
  width: '100%',
  height: "100%",
  hideMediaControl: true,
  mediacontrol: {
    seekbar: "#ffaa56",
    buttons: "#ff7f00"
  },
  autoPlay: true
});
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background: #000;
  ;
}
```

```html
<div style="width: 100%;">
  <div id="player"></div>
</div>

<img src="sv2.png" style="position:absolute;top:5px;right:10px" />
```

Java code

```
try {
    String userAgent = "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/54.0.2840.99 Safari/537.36";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://m.xemtvhd.com/vtv1.php").userAgent(userAgent).get();

    String url = doc.select("#xmlhttp.open").first().attr("data-source");

    System.out.println(url);

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Please support . Thank for support

Comment: The website you have in your example do not contains all the element which are in you screen, normal ?

Comment: @azro yeah. please see html in url http://m.tivi8k.net/htv1.php

Comment: @azro please support  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45313165/detect-text-in-script-and-obtain-text-within-script-tag-using-jsoup

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code will take all `<script>` elements and iterate over each, then it will check is the one he look is the one with the line you want **:** the `pattern` is here for, if it `matches` it will take the `group(1)` (represent the capturing group `(.*)`, the `group(0)` is the whole line) :

```
Elements script = doc.select("script");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("xmlhttp.open\\(\"GET\", \"(.*)\", false\\)");
                                                    //  ^^ is the capturing group
String url = "";

for (Element element : script) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(element.data());
    if (m.find()){
        url = m.group(1);
    }
}
System.out.println(url); //-> http://...542988
```

Comment: Another one going to hell trying to parse xml to regex, it will make you insane and others you fool into that lost quest ;) check this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/24099

Seriously now do use a parser not regex....