# Detect text in script and Obtain text within script tag using Jsoup

Tags: javascript, java, android, jsoup

I want to code get value stream but fail.
url detect http://m.xemtvhd.com/vtv1.php

How to get value stream : http://123.30.215.65/hls/4545780bfa790819/5/3/d836ad614748cdab11c9df291254cf836f21144da20bf08142455a8735b328ca/dnR2MQ==_m.m3u8 using Jsoup ?

```html
    <html>
 <head>
  <style>html,body{margin:0;padding:0;background:#000;;}</style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/clappr/latest/clappr.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
 </head>      
 <body> 
  <div style="width: 100%;"> 
  </div> 
  <div id="player"></div> 
  <script>
 player = new Clappr.Player({source: "http://123.30.215.65/hls/4545780bfa790819/5/3/d836ad614748cdab11c9df291254cf836f21144da20bf08142455a8735b328ca/dnR2MQ==_m.m3u8",
   parentId: '#player',
   width: '100%', height: "100%",
      hideMediaControl: true,
      autoPlay: true
             }); 
 </script>   
 </body>
</html>
```

Code Java me :

```html
Elements script = doc.select("script");
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("player = new Clappr.Player(\\(\"source:{\", \"(.*)\", false\\)");
                                                    //  ^^ is the capturing group
String url = "";

for (Element element : script) {
    Matcher m = p.matcher(element.data());
    if (m.find()){
        url = m.group(1);
    }
}
System.out.println(url);
```

please support . thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is some mistakes in your regex, for ex you put the `{` after `source` in fact it's before and you need to double escape it because `{i,j}` are quantifiers, and the `,` is also not at good place, I don't know why you did that, it's not the same order than the sentence

So to fix use : `Pattern.compile("player = new Clappr\\.Player\\(\\{source: \"(http:.*)\",.*");`

When you use regex, try online like [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and write the regex like word by word, and at the end you can try to replace word/group by \d, \w,... to reduce

Comment: not sucess ? I tried and it works for me so, I don't know what to tell you

Comment: when i run debug . i get value http://sv1.upsieutoc.com/2017/07/26/qqw.png and url html: http://m.xemtvhd.com/vtv1.php . i newbie :'( . please support thank pro.

Comment: `".*player(\\n|\\t|.)*source.*(http:.*)\".*"` try this, i've simplify because on your debug image it seems to have new lines or spaces that you don't specify in your post, https://ideone.com/MEGf9y It works here

Comment: thank bro. get value success. i verry happy. i like you.

Comment: HI bro Azro I have a question below !

Comment: @HuỳnhAí If new question write a new post, if not please edit first one, and reformulate i did not understand at all ^^

Comment: Bro @Azro i new post question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45337576/i-cant-get-value-from-script-in-android . please support hihi

Comment: @Bro Azro please support me

Comment: you may work a bit, the code is about the same

Answer (score 0):

@zaro why code regex not support get code script.it with a similar format

```
<head>
  <style>html,body{margin:0;padding:0;background:#000;;}</style>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/clappr/latest/clappr.min.js"></script>
  <meta name="referrer" content="no-referrer">
 </head>      
 <body> 
  <div style="width: 100%;"> 
  </div> 
  <div id="player"></div> 
  <script>
    player = new Clappr.Player({source:"http://123.30.215.47/hls/4545780bfa790819/5/3/4b3850f3b3e966aea6ee715c73493ee773f6c45ec2a942b35c941abff6b44e16/dnR2MQ==_m.m3u8",
                                parentId: '#player',
                                width: '100%', height: "50%",
                                hideMediaControl: true,
                                mediacontrol: {seekbar: "#f00", buttons: "#ff0"},
                                poster: 'https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-jHMLMVGcPhI/VqRirYSK0OI/AAAAAAAACEQ/F34hsicLLsU/s600-Ic42/xemtv.png',
                                position: 'top-right',
                                autoPlay: true
                            }); 
    </script> 
  <iframe scrolling="no" src="vtv1-pc.php" allowfullscreen="true" width="100%" frameborder="0" height="50%"></iframe> 
 </body>
</html>
```